# Angular Reactive Forms handle two level / dimensional checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 6/7 with **reactive** forms, I have a form with a list of permissions(two checkboxes in one row), for example, lets say each checkbox is a permission, by default the second checkbox in the row needs to be disabled on the first load and only enabled when the user clicks/checks the first checkbox in the row.

The flow:

1. The user can only click on the first checkbox in the row, for example, permission1,2,3 or 4.
2. If the user clicks/checks the first checkbox in the row, onChange event I need to enable the second checkbox.
3. On Submit - I need to fetch the ids of permissions and also if the user clicked on the second checkbox in of the rows, I need to fetch/save that information as a boolean flag, for example, lets say canGrantPermission: true/false.

Super simple code example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibb7ps

At the end I would like to have something like this:

```
permissions: [
  {permissionId: 1, canGrant: false}, 
  {permissionId: 2, canGrant: true}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution is based on the assumption you don't need a `FormControl` on the second checkbox, if you do, please let me know.

---

You can do something like below to accomplish this.

Create templatRef `#firstCheck` on input one

```
<input #firstCheck type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" (change)="onPermissionChange(i)">
```

On input two disabled second check if `#firstCheck` is checked `[disabled]="!firstCheck.checked"`, then create tempalteRef `#secondCheck` and set `secondCheck.checked` value to `orders.allowGrant` on click.

```
<input #secondCheck type="checkbox" [disabled]="!firstCheck.checked" (click)="orders[i].allowGrant = secondCheck.checked">
```

In `submit()` push values to `resultsArray` if first box is checked and console.log

```
  const resultsArray = []
      for(let i = 0; i < this.form.get('orders').value.length; i++){
        if(this.form.get('orders').value[i]){
          resultsArray.push({id:this.orders[i].id, allowGrant:this.orders[i].allowGrant})
        }
      }

    console.log(resultsArray);
```

---

To un-check second checkbox on first deselect you can do something like below.

I did this all in the view without method... set `secondCheck` and `allowGrant` to false on first click, use `(change)` on `secondCheck` instead of `(click)` like I had before.

```
 <input #firstCheck type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" (change)="onPermissionChange(i); secondCheck.checked = false; orders[i].allowGrant = secondCheck.checked">
    <input #secondCheck type="checkbox" [disabled]="!firstCheck.checked" (change)="orders[i].allowGrant = secondCheck.checked">  </label>
```

please see revised stackblitz

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpcz82?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Wow @Marshal, pretty much everything is working as needed for me, just one thing, do you know how can I fix in your example this problem, that first and second checkbox is checked and then the user clicks Only one the first checkbox, and it needs to disable/uncheck also the second checkbox(disabled) in one go? Do I need to user [checked]="" here for that?

Comment: *The user clicks only on the first checkbox

Comment: But now I can't uncheck the second checkbox if both of them are checked on stackblitz, do you know how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: sorry about that, see revision to answer and stackblitz. Revision is using the view only

Comment: Everything works as needed, thanks for your time - @Marshal, have a nice day! :)